# Relationship between title/question/answer length and the number of votes

Tags: discussion, voting, down-votes

I believe votes should be 'mainly' based on the quality of the question (Q) asked or answer (A) provided. However, I anecdotally see upvotes/downvotes based on how brief or detailed is the question/answer or even the title. This could potentially be misleading to the users.

Is there any analysis done on the relationship between upvotes/downvotes and title/question/answer style? I mean by style; length, punctuation, certain words,..etc).

Comment: Why people vote is up to them, no one can know there reasoning, so IDK what data you could be looking for and as you say this is anecdotal, it seems you are just inferring reasons for votes based on IDK what because you cannot know why someone voted the way they did.

Comment: [Related question on Mathematics Meta](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/26279/228959). My answer contains a SEDE query for analysis, those can be run on the data of any Stack Exchange site, the results of which were posted as comments by Stella Biderman.

Comment: Could you expand on "*This could potentially be misleading to the users.*", especially what do you mean by misleading?

Comment: I think you’re going to have a very hard time distinguishing between “quality” and “style”, particularly if you include under the rubric “style” things like “how detailed the question or answer is”, “length”, “proper punctuation”, etc.

Comment: See also: [Is there a demonstrable correlation between question length and question quality?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225367/323179) (here on MSE) and [“Are these sentences correct?”—Is a title like this enough reason to close a question?](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6680/191178) (on Meta ELU)

Comment: @SensibleAlexander It is misleading in the sense that an answer will considered to be the best although there are some other better answers but they are just written in different style

Comment: @Glorfindel That makes sense, although as you mentioned data are not quite enough to draw conclusions about what is optimal.