# Is there an optimal post length?

Tags: discussion, statistics

Obviously, it depends on the question/answer you're posting. But on *average*, is there some magic number of characters that will get you the best reputation bump?

My original hypothesis was that we'd get a unimodal shaped graph, increasing towards some optimal value as more information was added to posts, and then decreasing as the posts became overly verbose. Of course, I wasn't expecting an exact integer number that was the magic length e.g. 1047. Rather, I would have expected a sort of window in which the posts performed best.

I set out to investigate this, just for our biggest site, [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/), and composed a query that gives us a map from post length to average score:

https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1239083/postlengthvsaveragescore

The results: there seems to be some truth to my original hypothesis, but much noise. I ran the above query and then ran it again three more times, each time restricting the post score by some upper limit to try to remove outliers. Below are the results. Can someone with a statistical background improve on these results and provide a solid interpretation of them?

In the following graphs we have number of characters on the x axis and average score on the y axis. I should really have labelled the graphs (will do next time).

### No Limit on Score

It seems to be an ever so gentle slope upwards and then downwards, but it's fairly flat for the most part, other than the outliers.

[image]

### Score <= 100

Again, there are what look like outliers. But there's a pretty smooth looking shape up to around 16K and then outliers start to dominate. The sweet spot seems to be between 16K and 30K.

[image]

### Score <= 20

It seems to be a sweet spot between around 24K and 33K, roughly.

[image]

### Smoothing

Perhaps what's needed to make these results more sensible is some sort of sliding-window smoothing. For the <= 20 case, we see the graph jump between positive and negative values. This demonstrates that we probably don't have enough data to plot the "true" relationship between exact number of characters and average score, i.e. the relationship that would emerge as we approached an infinite number of posts.

A commenter below points out that binning is probably what we want here.

### Update

All of the above graphs were quickly mocked up in Excel; an astute commenter points out that this is probably the reason for the rounding to integer values causing the very weird choppy looking final graph. The related question gives more statistically sound results, and should be consulted instead of this one. Also, the related question talks exclusively about question length rather than merely post length. From a data analysis point of view this probably makes more sense. Questions and answers are different things so mixing up their analysis as above probably doesn't make sense.

Another problem with the above is that we are missing the sample size per data point. Sample size is crucial when attempting to draw any statistical conclusions from data.

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225367/is-there-a-demonstrable-correlation-between-question-length-and-question-quality

Comment: Re *"some sort of sliding-window smoothing"*: Or just [binning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_binning) (perhaps using the median value instead of the average value (given the "outliers")). We have no reason to believe there are any special post lengths, e.g. that post length 28791 is somewhat special compared to post length 28792. Alternatively, use a non-linear y axis scale (say logarithmic).

Comment: [You should label both x- and y axes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pPJf8KrvJXU&t=10m54s) on the plots (I know it is not exactly intuitive in Excel, but it is possible). For instance, the last graph's y axis *seems* different (it is probably not the logarithm of the average score, but it seems odd that *average* scores (how many samples?) could come out negative).

Comment: Why are there only discrete values on the last graph? Why would an average score only have integer values? You haven't used Python 2 for computing this, have you?

Comment: A resolution of 1.0 is too coarse when most of the average scores are in the range 0.0 - 3.0.

Comment: What is the sample size? In the millions? Can you add the sample size for each post length to the query/output? And perhaps also the sum so the average can be computed by other means (e.g. if SEDE can not do it)?

Comment: Probably SQL avg function caused rounding error

Comment: Yep I think I should have done this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11106170/sql-avg-returning-an-int