# Is there a Demonstrable Correlation between Question/Answer Length and Reputation?

Tags: discussion, statistics

Is the length of a question or answer positively correlated to a user's reputation? The fineprint:

- We'd like to explore questions and answers separately as they are qualitatively different things.
- We need to be sure we're measuring reputation *at the time of posting*, not now. However, we may have to settle for an approximation of this measure, if it proves difficult to retrieve efficiently from the [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/).

### Motivation: To Clarify The "Shorter is Better" vs. "Longer is Better" Paradox

An [existing answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225367/is-there-a-demonstrable-correlation-between-question-length-and-question-quality/225376#225376) demonstrates a correlation between question length and question score. It demonstrates an even stronger correlation between answer length and score. The simple conclusion is that "The longer the post, the higher quality it is." However, this appears to contradict an [existing blog post](https://blog.overops.com/the-anatomy-of-a-great-stack-overflow-question-after-analyzing-10000/) which correlates lower scores to better questions, right down to 200-300 character questions:

> There’s no such thing as too short, either — really short questions
>   (around 200-300 characters) received the best results.

So what's the rub? Well, my hypothesis is that reputation acts as a [confounder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confounding) influencing both post length and score. More specifically, I believe:

- Higher rep users are likely to write more detailed posts. They're generally more expert in certain fields, so their questions necessarily include more detail. And they tend to go for the less simple questions to answer too, looking for the "big challenges" over the trivial stuff- questions which demand longer answers than the typical question.
- Higher rep users are more likely to receive a higher score on any given post. This is just a hypothesis but there are results out there that support it, e.g. the power law distribution of reputation shown in [Distribution of Reputation: Power Law?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21259/distribution-of-reputation-power-law) and https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/04/13/stack-overflow-voting-pattern-analysis/.

---

Note: in the blog post, "good" doesn't just take score into account. Perhaps the only apparent "Paradox" is the definition of "good" as a question getting a fast, quality answer vs. the total score. Still, it's worth investigating the reputation vs. length correlation to better understand the results of the other Meta SE answer.

Comment: Enter the SEDE wizzards

Comment: My experience is that long, precise, contextualized, question (that require a serious effort to understand because the problem is indeed complex or have very specific need that require an explanation) have a tendancy to be downvoted as if it was a "TL;DR" button.

Comment: as long as you define "really short" to be hundreds of characters, you'll not think about the "title says it all" questions and the "don't do that" answers, will you?

Comment: I would rather expected a correlation of length with score (positive for answers and negative for questions).

Answer (score 10):

**TL;DR: Yes (just), but not the one you think.**

I pulled the statistics. This is a scatter graph of reputation to average post length on Stack Overflow, limited to reputation <= 20000 and post length <= 5000 to remove the outliers.

[image]

That red line is the trend line. In other words, this is showing that higher reputation users write *shorter* answers - about 350 characters fewer on average for a 20k user as for a 1-rep user. Perhaps they've all learned the art of conciseness?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/1482/discussion-on-answer-by-artofcode-is-there-a-demonstrable-correlation-between-qu).

Answer (score 3):

The [other answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/348349/763245) demonstrates a negative correlation between reputation and average post length on Stack Overflow. This is based on a query that fetches all types of record from the Posts table, including tag excerpts and tag wikis as well as questions and answers. Tag excerpts and wikis tend to be shorter than questions and answers, possibly biasing the result if higher-reputation users make more tag excerpts.

On Literature Stack Exchange, by contrast, taking only questions and answers, and ignoring other post types, there is a *positive* correlation between reputation and average length of questions and answers, as shown below.

[image]

Notes:

1. The post asks for a correlation based on "reputation at the time of posting". I don't know how to do this based on the data in SEDE—this only includes current user reputation. I suppose one could estimate it by linear interpolation, but I am not sure that there is a principled reason to do this, since we don't know which direction the causation goes in—does reputation affect verbosity, or does verbosity affect reputation, or both?
2. A two-sided permutation test finds that the correlation is significant at the 0.4% level, but the R² is tiny: just 1% of the length of posts is explained by the reputation of the user. This suggests that the correlation has little or no practical explanatory value.
3. On Literature, higher-reputation users tend to make more tag excerpts, so that if we include all post types, the correlation is still positive, but R² is reduced to 0.004, less than half the value for questions and answers only.

Comment: What query are you using to generate this?

Comment: [Reputation and average length of questions & answers by user](https://data.stackexchange.com/literature/query/1243187/)

Comment: Thanks for this sound statistical approach & well spotted removing the tag excerpts. I still think Qs vs As might give us more of an insight though, and there is certainly more research to be done on other sites. The reason I suspect Qs and As to differ is due to the large amount of short, concise, useful As that high rep users pump out. Whereas if we look at Qs asked by high rep users, I'd imagine if you're a high rep user and you need to ask a Q... it's necessarily complicated.